# What is the technique / method to create this photo?

Tags: technique

I can program in Python (Opencv) a little bit and would like to know which steps can be automated, if any, in the creation of this image, as I would like to do similar images for friends.

Does anyone know the technique to do this photo?

[image]
https://twitter.com/CB_Ignoranza/status/1278074393923661834/photo/1

Is it done through an algorithm or some manual work on the computer?

Also asked here: https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/8759/what-is-the-technique-method-to-create-this-photo

Comment: Do you have access to Photoshop? It would be a lot easier to do this is in an image editor than to code it from scratch. There are 3 main steps to this: 1. Create the *word cloud*. Probably easiest to use some online service. 2. Distort the word cloud using some kind of *displacement map* so it follows the surface of the portrait. 3. Use the words as a *mask* on the portrait so the portrait is only visible inside the words.

Comment: @Wolff: Thanks for your suggestion. However the main point is the 3d - distortion of the  the word cloud. I could do the word cloud in python and the other steps. However the main question is, do you think, that the 3d-distortion is done from the 2d-image or is it done via another mask which could not be of the same person?

Comment: I can't be sure, but it looks like it's just using a grayscale version of the portrait.

Comment: .. [displacement map](https://photoshopcafe.com/tutorials/dispmap/dispmap.htm)...